# Applications deployed in one of the managed servers in weblogic server 12c are not showing up on the control tab

Tags: weblogic12c

I am running 2 weblogic managed servers on a weblogic console. All Applications deployed on one of the servers are available in controls tab to stop and start. But all applications deployed on the second server do not appear on the controls tab. Is there any setting at managed server level for this?

I tired looking for the setting but was unable to find any.

Comment: Did you target your application to both managed servers ?

Comment: No, Both servers have separate different applications. I am sorry. I did not see your comment early. I am very new to stackoverflow.